# Reduce number of activities in android

Tags: android

i am new android programmer.
I'm trying to create my app contains one list of lessons (40 items) and each lesson contains 12 part and each part has one image, one text and one button for play a sound.
so i would like others to explain, how can i create this app, for me?
do this app need to create 40 activity for lessons or no?
please help me for this.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one container activity and 2 fragments.
1 fragment for holding lessons list
another fragment for a particular lesson. The lesson fragment can have any views you want. You just need to update the contents of your lesson fragment for every different lesson.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you tell me where i can read more about contents update please?

Comment: hello again. excuse me can you tell me how can i create a leitner app for learning vocabulary?